# Can't find variable panresponder

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a beginner for react-native, my assignment is in functional react native form. I wish someone can help me solve this problem. This is the class component react-native code
from this source: https://github.com/nathvarun/React-Native-Layout-Tutorial-Series/blob/master/Project%20Files/12%20Tinder%20Swipe%20Deck/%232%20Complete%20Animation/App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, Animated, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
const Users = [
  { id: "1", uri: require('./assets/1.jpg') },
  { id: "2", uri: require('./assets/2.jpg') },
  { id: "3", uri: require('./assets/3.jpg') },
  { id: "4", uri: require('./assets/4.jpg') },
  { id: "5", uri: require('./assets/5.jpg') },
]

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.position = new Animated.ValueXY()
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0
    }

    this.rotate = this.position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
      outputRange: ['-10deg', '0deg', '10deg'],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    this.rotateAndTranslate = {
      transform: [{
        rotate: this.rotate
      },
      ...this.position.getTranslateTransform()
      ]
    }

    this.likeOpacity = this.position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
      outputRange: [0, 0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })
    this.dislikeOpacity = this.position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
      outputRange: [1, 0, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    this.nextCardOpacity = this.position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
      outputRange: [1, 0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })
    this.nextCardScale = this.position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
      outputRange: [1, 0.8, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.PanResponder = PanResponder.create({

      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {

        this.position.setValue({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy })
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {

        if (gestureState.dx > 120) {
          Animated.spring(this.position, {
            toValue: { x: SCREEN_WIDTH + 100, y: gestureState.dy }
          }).start(() => {
            this.setState({ currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1 }, () => {
              this.position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
            })
          })
        }
        else if (gestureState.dx < -120) {
          Animated.spring(this.position, {
            toValue: { x: -SCREEN_WIDTH - 100, y: gestureState.dy }
          }).start(() => {
            this.setState({ currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1 }, () => {
              this.position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
            })
          })
        }
        else {
          Animated.spring(this.position, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            friction: 4
          }).start()
        }
      }
    })
  }

  renderUsers = () => {

    return Users.map((item, i) => {


      if (i < this.state.currentIndex) {
        return null
      }
      else if (i == this.state.currentIndex) {

        return (
          <Animated.View
            {...this.PanResponder.panHandlers}
            key={item.id} style={[this.rotateAndTranslate, { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }]}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.likeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.dislikeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
              source={item.uri} />

          </Animated.View>
        )
      }
      else {
        return (
          <Animated.View

            key={item.id} style={[{
              opacity: this.nextCardOpacity,
              transform: [{ scale: this.nextCardScale }],
              height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute'
            }]}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
              source={item.uri} />

          </Animated.View>
        )
      }
    }).reverse()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {this.renderUsers()}
        </View>
        <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

        </View>


      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

This I rewrite in functional component react-native but it gets the error cant get panresponder

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, Animated, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
const Users = [
  { id: "1", uri: require('../image/antman.jpg') },
  { id: "2", uri: require('../image/butterfly.jpg') },
  { id: "3", uri: require('../image/captainmarvel.jpg') },
  { id: "4", uri: require('../image/antman.jpg') },
  { id: "5", uri: require('../image/antman.jpg') },
]

const SignUpScreen = () => {

  const position = new Animated.ValueXY()
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  //const [PanResponder,setPanResponder] = useState('');
  const rotate = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: ['-10deg', '0deg', '10deg'],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })

  const rotateAndTranslate = {
    transform: [{
      rotate: rotate
    },
    ...position.getTranslateTransform()
    ]
  }

  const likeOpacity = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [0, 0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })
  const dislikeOpacity = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [1, 0, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })

  const nextCardOpacity = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [1, 0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })
  const nextCardScale = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })


  useEffect(() => {
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({

      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {

        position.setValue({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy })
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {

        if (gestureState.dx > 120) {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: SCREEN_WIDTH + 100, y: gestureState.dy }
          }).start(() => {
            setState({ currentIndex: currentIndex + 1 }, () => {
              position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
            })
          })
        }
        else if (gestureState.dx < -120) {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: -SCREEN_WIDTH - 100, y: gestureState.dy }
          }).start(() => {
            setState({ currentIndex: currentIndex + 1 }, () => {
              position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
            })
          })
        }
        else {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            friction: 4
          }).start()
        }
      }
    })
  })


  renderUsers = () => {

    return Users.map((item, i) => {


      if (i < currentIndex) {
        return null
      }
      else if (i == currentIndex) {

        return (
          <Animated.View
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
            key={item.id} style={[rotateAndTranslate, { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }]}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: likeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: dislikeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
              source={item.uri} />

          </Animated.View>
        )
      }
      else {
        return (
          <Animated.View

            key={item.id} style={[{
              opacity: nextCardOpacity,
              transform: [{ scale: nextCardScale }],
              height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute'
            }]}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
              source={item.uri} />

          </Animated.View>
        )
      }
    }).reverse()
  }


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {renderUsers()}
      </View>
      <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

      </View>


    </View>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default SignUpScreen;
```

Comment: useEffect only runs after the component has rendered, so your panResponder setup hasn't initiated before your render. Try taking your panResponder setup outside of useEffect. Just have it run within the SignUpScreen component on its own, not within useEffect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment, try taking the `panResponder` setup outside of `useEffect`.

**EDIT**: You have a couple additional issues in your code. One thing I think you hadn't understood is how to update state using React hooks.

When you declare a state in hooks, you use the following syntax:

`const [someNum, setSomeNum] = useState(0); // <- anything can go inside this, a number, object, array, etc.`

In this case, `someNum` is equal to `0`. Then, when you want to update state, you use the second argument in the above declaration, like so:

`setSomeNum(10);`

Notice how `setSomeNum` is the second argument in the original declaration. Now, `someNum` is equal to `10`.

I've tried to go through the code below to help identify those spots and show you how to do it and added comments where I've made changes. There may be some other errors I haven't spotted, but this should clean up your code quite a bit.

```
const SignUpScreen = () => {

  // 1. must useState here since you are changing this value
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY());

  // ...

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
      // this is how you update state in hooks with Animated Values.
      setPosition(new Animated.ValueXY({x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy});
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {

        if (gestureState.dx > 120) {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: SCREEN_WIDTH + 100, y: gestureState.dy }
          }).start(() => {
            // this is how you update state. they will update simultaneously
           // if you require that setPosition be called AFTER setCurrentIndex (as in your original code), you can do so using useEffect
            setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
            setPosition(new AnimatedValue({x: 0, y: 0 });
          })
        }
        else if (gestureState.dx < -120) {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: -SCREEN_WIDTH - 100, y: gestureState.dy }
          }).start(() => {
            // see explanation above
            setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
            setPosition(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 });
          })
        }
        else {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            friction: 4
          }).start()
        }
      }
    })
  })


  renderUsers = () => {

    return Users.map((item, i) => {


      if (i < currentIndex) {
        return null
      }
      else if (i == currentIndex) {

        return (
          <Animated.View
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
            key={item.id} style={[rotateAndTranslate, { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }]}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: likeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: dislikeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
              source={item.uri} />

          </Animated.View>
        )
      }
      else {
        return (
          <Animated.View

            key={item.id} style={[{
              opacity: nextCardOpacity,
              transform: [{ scale: nextCardScale }],
              height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute'
            }]}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>LIKE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: 0, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
              <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>NOPE</Text>

            </Animated.View>

            <Image
              style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
              source={item.uri} />

          </Animated.View>
        )
      }
    }).reverse()
  }


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {renderUsers()}
      </View>
      <View style={{ height: 60 }}>

      </View>


    </View>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default SignUpScreen;
```

Comment: But after that shows me error message "State Updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()

Comment: Thanks for it, but still have some bugs, the cards cant swipe it